# Passing data in viewbag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to retrieve the hours column from the table `db.instantservices` 
I am not able to do it .I am using `EF code` and on the browser I am able to see this details page but not the information in the `viewbag`.Thank you in advance

```
Classes-:


 public class InstantService
{
    public int InstantServiceID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string InstantUserName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }``
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int InstantID { get; set; }
    public Instants CurrentInstant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}


public class Review
{
    public int ReviewID { get; set; }
    public InstantService Service { get; set; }
    public int InstantServiceID { get; set; }
    public string MyReview{ get; set; }
}
```

But when using this code i dont get any  value.
Code -:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
         {
           Review review = db.ReviewDB.Find(id);
            ViewBag.ServiceHours = db.InstantServiceDB.Select(model => model.Hours);
            return View(review);
          }
```

in view code-:

```
                 @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Details";
                  }


             <fieldset>
            <legend>Review</legend>

             <div class="display-label">Service</div>
             <div class="display-field">
             @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Service.Title)
             </div>

             <div class="display-label">MyReview</div>
             <div class="display-field">
             @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyReview)
             </div>
             </fieldset>

             <p>
             @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ReviewID }) |
             @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
             </p>
             <div>
             Total Hours required were -:
             <div>
             @ViewBag.ServiceHours
             </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Try `ViewBag.ServiceHours = db.InstantServiceDB.Select(model => model.Hours).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method (the Linq *Select*) returns an *IEnumerable*:

```
db.InstantServiceDB.Select(model => model.Hours);
```

When you dump that directly into the Razor view, it's going to get rendered using *ToString*, which you wouldn't want.  If you're expecting a single result from that database call, then you could use *FirstOrDefault* to get the actual value:

```
ViewBag.ServiceHours = db.InstantServiceDB
    .Where(model => model.ForeignKey == id)
    .Select(model => model.Hours)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help.I want to retrieve the no. of hours of that InstantService for which the review is there.

Comment: @user1609429 It's hard for me to say exactly without knowing more about *db.InstantServiceDB*.  The key is to make sure that the right-hand side of your expression returns a string.

Comment: something like  ViewBag.ServiceHours =   db.InstantServiceDB.Select(model => model.Hours).Where("Foriegnkey_OF_InstantServices_Table" = PrimaryKeyID_OF_Reviews_Table ,); So what should be these values for the same.and moreover how to write the WHERE clause here.Thank YOu

Comment: @user1609429 please see my updated answer.  Just replace "ForeignKey" with the name of the foreign key column in your model.

Comment: Thank you so much.This is exactly what i was looking for.!! :).Also please tell me is this a good way to implement in a real world app. ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how exactly you want the `ViewBag.ServiceHours` data displayed. Since, given by the assignment, it is a collection of integers, you might display it e.g. in this way in the view:

```
<div>
    @(String.Join(", ", ((IEnumerable<int>) ViewBag.ServiceHours).Select(x => x.ToString())))
</div>
```

This will display all the values separated by a comma. You can adjust the format to fit your needs.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help.The 2 data tables are related by a foriegn key ,you can see in the code.The code you have given was very helpful BUT is showing the first row everytime which is not intended instead I want the no. of hours of that instant service for which the review is being displayed.Can you please tell.?